# How to show line numbers of devtools

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, devtools

This is devtools screen:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIr2o.png)

And i tried search settings , and right click menu

Comment: You must be on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking questions.

Comment: I have already described this issue very clearly, and this is not the reason for you to give a negative review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is caused by a setting called "**Automatically pretty print in the Sources Panel**" which seems to be set as default. In this case, the "wrong" line numbers after pretty-print are actually consistent with those of the minified code.

For example, if you only have **1 line** in your minified code, you will only have **Line 1, Column xxx** after pretty-print.

In short, you can simply turn off **Automatically pretty print in the Sources Panel** at `DevTool Settings --> Experiments --> Automatically pretty print in the Sources Panel`, and reload DevTools.